# SharePoint 2007 to 2010 upgrade error: Duplicate content type name was found

Tags: sharepoint, upgrade

I'm in the process of doing an upgrade from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 using the database attach method.
During the database upgrade I'm getting the following error:

```
Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'PublishingSite' (Id: 'f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa') in Site 'http://intranet'. Exception: A duplicate content type name "Resource" was found
```

I've had a look around and found two possible solutions, but I wanted to know if anyone has tried these and which one (if any) worked.

[The first solution is from TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288476.aspx) which suggests renaming the "Resource" content type as there is a name conflict with the new 2010 content types.

[The second solution](http://blog.njpenterprises.com/archive/2009/12/18/one-or-more-fieldtypes-are-not-installed-properly-after-upgrading-site-from-2007-to-2010.aspx) suggests deactivating the Publishing feature and deleting the "Relationship List" list.

I'm a bit nervous about trying them as both seem to have the potential to break the site.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up attaching the database to the Web Application and it turned out that the site still worked, except for some reporting services web parts. I replaced them with the latest version and all seems well.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the Technet solution and changed the name of the content type.  In my case, both were called "Resource", I changed one to "Group Resource" and everything was great after that.